# How to find which Signature Method NetSuite uses for TBA - HMAC-SHA256 or HMAC-SHA1?

Tags: netsuite, restlet, restlet-2.0

I need to know which Signature method NetSuite uses currently in my account for TBA.

HMAC-SHA256 or HMAC-SHA1 ?

NetSuite version - 2022.1
I am using NetSuite restlet based implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default HMAC SHA256 is supported. Then end of support for HMAC-SHA1 announced for 2021.2 has been postponed. Accounts can disable HMAC-SHA1 but cannot (at this time) disable HMAC-SHA256 so just use that.

If you need to know that SHA1 has been disabled you can run this in the console. or use the method in a script:

```js
require(['N/runtime'], runtime=>{
    console.log(runtime.isFeatureInEffect({feature:'KILLSHA1FORTBA'}));
});
```

Comment: This returns false. What does this means ?

Comment: It means you could still use SHA1. Note that if this is a new integration you should not use SHA1 even if it is still available. If you have the opportunity you should convert existing integrations that use SHA1 to SHA256

Comment: @bknights can u tell me how to generate HMAC-SHA256 code if i got the credentials for my TBA endpoint rest api?